# Facebook image viewer Ajax history - how they do that?

Tags: javascript, facebook, url

- in facebook photo.php script when we
  click on picture or next or previous
  picture button, it use ajax to move
  to next and prvious picture using ajax without page reload.
- when i click even on back button of
  brower in facebook it use ajax again to load
  previous picture instead load previous page....
- what's my problem, when i click on
  back button of browser in my code, control goes to my previous page
  instead of previous picture in div tag ...
- i know there is some change in
  Address bar URL in facebook when we
  click on next and previous button in
  facebook ... **how facebook is doing
  that**

Answer (score 1):

Either the [hashbang technique](http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) or [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.c2.a0method)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hash mark trick (#).
Here is a reference:
http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/fixing-the-back-button-and-enabling-bookmarking-for-ajax-apps
http://ajaxonomy.com/2007/web-design/a-better-ajax-back-button-solution